# Save Pointer Flutter Parse

Tags: flutter, parse-platform

I am trying to save a "pointer" using Parse SDK for Flutter and am getting the error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in the debug console. Due to some research I know that error usually indicates a function called within a function for a never-ending loop.

Below is the `Row()` that holds the `addToCart()` function (of which is breaking the code). The `FutureBuilder` widget is used to tell if the user is currently logged in and send them to the login screen if not. Otherwise they can add an item to their cart. I need to add a pointer to the Products class using productID in the Cart table.

The cart table is set up to receive a pointer parseObject data type, as if I replace `..set('productID',(ParseObject('Products')..objectId = ParseObject("Products").objectId))` with `..set('productID',widget.productID)` I get an error that says "wrong data type for parseObject pointer" (paraphrasing).

Lastly, If I change the data type from pointer to just a string and place in a string value, the code works and I can save records to the database. So I am not exactly sure why my pointer saving is not working.

```
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                FutureBuilder(
                    future: ParseUser.currentUser(),
                    builder: ((context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () => addToCart(),
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 203, 59),
                              onPrimary: Colors.black),
                          child: const Text("Add to Cart"),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/LogIn');
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 203, 59),
                              onPrimary: Colors.black),
                          child: const Text("Add to Cart"),
                        );
                      }
                    })),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/products/',
                        arguments: widget.productId);
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 203, 59),
                      onPrimary: Colors.black),
                  child: const Text("Product Details"),
                ),
              ],
            )
```

```
  Future<void> addToCart() async {
    ParseUser currentUser = await ParseUser.currentUser() as ParseUser;
    final addToCart = ParseObject('Cart')
      ..set(
          'productID',
          (ParseObject('Products')
            ..objectId = ParseObject("Products").objectId))
      ..set('userID', currentUser.objectId)
      ..set('quantity', qtyDropdownValue)
      ..set('subtotal',
          widget.productPrice.toDouble() * qtyDropdownValue.toDouble())
      ..set('productSize', sizeDropdownValue);
    await addToCart.save();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work this out for any one who looks at this in the future.

Here is the working code.

```
  Future<void> addToCart() async {
    ParseUser currentUser = await ParseUser.currentUser() as ParseUser;
    var addToCart = ParseObject('Cart')
      ..set(
          'productID',
          (ParseObject("Products")..objectId = widget.productObjectId)
              .toPointer())
      ..set('userID', currentUser.objectId)
      ..set('quantity', qtyDropdownValue)
      ..set('subtotal',
          widget.productPrice.toDouble() * qtyDropdownValue.toDouble())
      ..set('productSize', sizeDropdownValue);
    await addToCart.save();
    showSuccess("Item Added to Cart!");
  }
```

The showSuccess function at the end is an added function that doesn't need to be there. But as you can see, I really just needed to add a variable that defines the objectId for the object that I was trying to add to the cart. In my earlier code, I was not defining the specific object but instead just pointing it towards the Products table in general.

Answer (score 1):

if you have any object id and you want to convert to pointer then use this

```
(ParseObject('User_Profile')..objectId = 
    "your_object_id").toPointer()
```

my side condition

```
..whereEqualTo(
   'Profile_Id',(ParseObject('User_Profile')..objectId = "33PwksUIKo").toPointer());
```